# How to measure the time elapsed during user input in Python?

Tags: python, timer

I want to measure the time a user took to answer a question and display it.

Comment: You have said what you want to do but not what your question is. Was there a particular problem when you wrote the code to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The function [`default_timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer)  of the standard library module `timeit` is made for this:

```py
import timeit

question = "What is the capital of France?"
start = timeit.default_timer()
answer = input(question + " ")
end = timeit.default_timer()
if answer.strip().lower() == "paris":
    print("Correct.")
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
print("You answered in {:.3f} s.".format(end - start))
```